# Expected number of transitions

Tags: probability, expected-value

I toss a fair coin $N$ times and $X$ is a RV that denotes number of transitions from heads to tails or from tails to heads in consecutive tosses. I have to find the expected value of $X$.

For this I have to find $P(X = k)$ where $k$ can vary from $1$ to $N-1$. I don't know how to handle this problem. I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Do you need an asymptotic value? In a naive way one could compute $P(X_n=+,X_{n-1}=-,...,X_1=- |X_0=-)$ ,i.e. the probability of having exactly n tosses of the same sign. taking the expectation one can compute the expected lentgh of a series of tosses of the same sign and call it $L$. Than I would expect that $N/L$ is asymptotically the number you are looking for.

Comment: The method above is not rigorous anyway so it could be wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually such questions are solved using indicator random variables. Let $\mathbb{1}_{i}$ denote the indicator random variable for the transition from toss number $i$ to $i + 1$. Thus, $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{i}] = P(\text{transition in } (i + 1)^{\text{th}} \text{ toss}) = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $i$.

Thus, we have $\displaystyle X = \sum_{i = 1}^{N-1} \mathbb{1}_i$. Hence, $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{i = 1}^{N-1} \mathbb{1}_i \right] = \sum_{i = 1}^{N-1} \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_i] = \sum_{i = 1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{N - 1}{2}$.

Comment: Nice and simple. For a non-fair coin with probability p of being up and q=1-p of being down do you think that the expectation of the indicator function becomes 2pq and the expected number of changes (N-1)2pq ?

Comment: @Thomas Yep that sounds right.